# Android things: How can I fix Doorbell example

Tags: android, logging, google-play-services, android-things

Recently, I've got raspberry pi 3 and I'm trying to run android things doorbell project. I build it in Android studio 3.0 and i did everything that explained in android things doorbell project. but when i build the app to raspberry pi, it doesn't work. When I try debugging, it terminates after few time passes(i didn't touch everything).
This is the system process debugging log. what do i have to do?

```js
08-16 08:03:13.434 412-426/system_process W/ActivityManager: Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
08-16 08:03:28.361 412-426/system_process W/ActivityManager: Timeout executing service: ServiceRecord{c4f101b u0 com.example.androidthings.doorbell/com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService}
                                                             
                                                             --------- beginning of main
08-16 08:03:28.397 412-426/system_process I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6135 SIG: 3
08-16 08:03:28.407 412-426/system_process I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 412 SIG: 3
08-16 08:03:28.407 412-417/system_process I/art: Thread[2,tid=417,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xa9b0d000,peer=0x12c010d0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
08-16 08:03:29.011 412-417/system_process I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-16 08:03:29.011 412-426/system_process I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 537 SIG: 3
08-16 08:03:29.903 412-426/system_process W/ProcessCpuTracker: Skipping unknown process pid 6351
08-16 08:03:30.473 412-426/system_process E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.example.androidthings.doorbell
                                                             PID: 6135
                                                             Reason: executing service com.example.androidthings.doorbell/com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService
                                                             Load: 0.63 / 0.31 / 0.32
                                                             CPU usage from 557691ms to 0ms ago (2017-08-16 07:54:10.671 to 2017-08-16 08:03:28.362):
                                                               3.4% 412/system_server: 2.5% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 2730 minor
                                                               2.4% 152/adbd: 0.2% user + 2.1% kernel / faults: 44173 minor
                                                               1.1% 1213/perfd: 0.6% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 186 minor
                                                               0.5% 6014/kworker/u8:1: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
                                                               0.5% 101/irq/92-mmc1: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
                                                               0.4% 6035/kworker/u8:2: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
                                                               0.3% 6024/kworker/u8:0: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                               0.3% 652/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0.3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1669 minor
                                                               0.3% 150/surfaceflinger: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1514 minor
                                                               0% 107/brcmf_wdog/mmc1: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 520/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 7/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 840/com.google.android.gms: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 88 minor
                                                               0% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 20/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 8/rcu_sched: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 127/logd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 14 minor
                                                               0% 169/metrics_collector: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 19 minor
                                                               0% 620/com.android.iotlauncher: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 20 minor
                                                               0% 104/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 149/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 170/metricsd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 756/com.google.process.gapps: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 19 minor
                                                               0% 16/ksoftirqd/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 148/lmkd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 5353/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 12/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 66/kworker/2:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 121/jbd2/mmcblk0p15: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 153/zygote: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 141 minor
                                                               0% 10/migration/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 19/migration/3: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 163/netd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 40 minor
                                                               0% 166/sh: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 102 minor
                                                               0% 172/update_engine: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                               0% 5981/kworker/1:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                              +0% 6046/kworker/2:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                              +0% 6048/kworker/3:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                              +0% 6135/com.example.androidthings.doorbell: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                              +0% 6219/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                              +0% 6337/dumpsys: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                             3.2% TOTAL: 1.6% user + 1.3% kernel + 0% iowait + 0.2% softirq
                                                             CPU usage from 1542ms to 2074ms later (2017-08-16 08:03:29.904 to 2017-08-16 08:03:30.436):
                                                               67% 412/system_server: 46% user + 20% kernel / faults: 3 minor
                                                                 31% 680/Binder:412_5: 26% user + 5.6% kernel
                                                                 28% 628/Binder:412_4: 18% user + 9.3% kernel
                                                                 5.6% 426/ActivityManager: 0% user + 5.6% kernel
                                                                 1.8% 716/Binder:412_6: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
                                                               5.1% 1213/perfd: 3.4% user + 1.7% kernel / faults: 6 minor
                                                                 1.7% 1223/perfd: 1.7% user + 0% kernel
                                                                 1.7% 1224/perfd: 1.7% user + 0% kernel
                                                                 1.7% 6149/Studio:PollMem: 0% user + 1.7% kernel
                                                               3.7% 152/adbd: 1.8% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 59 minor
                                                                 1.8% 152/adbd: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
                                                                 1.8% 1146/->host: 1.8% user + 0% kernel
                                                                 1.8% 1147/<-host: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
                                                               1.7% 6014/kworker/u8:1: 0% user + 1.7% kernel
                                                              +0% 6358/dumpsys: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                             26% TOTAL: 17% user + 9.1% kernel
08-16 08:03:30.476 412-427/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.androidthings.doorbell/.DoorbellActivity
08-16 08:03:30.483 412-427/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 6135:com.example.androidthings.doorbell/u0a28 (adj 0): user request after error
08-16 08:03:30.564 412-5697/system_process D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 6135
08-16 08:03:30.569 412-433/system_process I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Starting com.example.androidthings.doorbell) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2478 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2436 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2305 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2300 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:193 
08-16 08:03:30.614 412-424/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@79a2cdf attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@161884c
08-16 08:03:32.129 412-422/system_process I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 26801(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 14(880KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 2.427ms total 120.639ms
08-16 08:03:32.913 412-501/system_process I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.example.androidthings.doorbell appid=10028 user=0: from pid 6365
08-16 08:03:34.067 412-479/system_process E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
```

Comment: you didn't link to what you are doing, I'm guessing this: https://developer.android.com/things/training/doorbell/cloud-vision.html `i didn't touch everything` might be the problem. Did you _"Generate a new Android API key for your project as described in the Authenticating to a Cloud API Service guide."_. Next time post a MVCE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so that we can reproduce EXACTLY your issue

Comment: firstly, thx for your comment. I forgot to link the project doorbell and the link that you wrote is right. the sentence i didn't touch everything means that i didn't do step over or step into,etc after running app with debugging mode with the stop point at onCreate() function. I set the stop point at camera handler initiating in onCreate function to confirm the variable. After I began the debugging, I didn't do anything but it suddenly terminated a few minutes passed with the log thread signaled 3.